# I want to create 50 databases for 50 states dynamically and insert records to related database on tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I want to create 50 databases for 50 states dynamically and insert records of table factinternetsales from adventureworksdw database to related state database, how can I write sql script or built ssis pacakge

Comment: What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Multiple identical databases like you seem to be describing are *usually* the wrong way to solve whatever problem you're addressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "dynamic sql". Start with the database like so:

```
declare @stateName varchar(50) = 'MyState';

declare @cmd varchar(max) = 'create database ' + @stateName + ';';
execute (@cmd);
```

If you have your states in a table, you can loop over them by using a cursor and this kind of dynamic sql. After creating the databases you can create tables and do INSERTs in the same way.

Comment: But keep in mind what DatumPoint and alroc said: Try to solve your problem with one database instead of 50(!!!) as this gets a maintaining nightmare in many respects.